# Try two different domains for an exchange server in OSX

Tags: macos, networking, dns, exchange

Our mail server is accessible through domain1 on LAN and domain2 from outside.

Is it possible to round-robin a CNAME in OSX? Any other way to solve this (other than multiple Office identities, which is a PITA)?